# Force mobile chrome browser to change font size for dropdown options

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, dropdown

I want to change font size for dropdown options in chrome mobile browser. I have tried setting inline css with font-size attribute which seems to be changing font size for options in desktop browser but it does not work in mobile chrome browser. Is it not a supported behaviour for mobile browser? I have searched online for a solution, unable to get one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Search for **CSS Media Query** it will help you apply a certain CSS for specified screen width.

Comment: this link will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: This is not about media query. I am saying font-size does not have any effect on options when opened in android chrome browser. I used inline css too but did not get anything.